# Need to read a csv file that is in a different path than the one where jupyter notebook is run on

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am looking to read a csv file present in my local drive ex: C:\Users\Studyfolder\abc.csv
My python libraries are installed in another directory - a path created for python 3 libraries ex:C:\Users\Anaconda3_2\envs\py3

***On Anaconda Prompt***- i have set my cd path as - C:\Users\Anaconda3_2\envs\py3 since naturally, all python libraries will be installed there

***On Jupyter Notebook***, I am looking to read the csv file to extract the dataframe. For definite reason when i run the command
df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv'), the file wouldn't be found under the path cd'd on Anaconda prompt

Should i be saving all my data files in the same path where python libraries are installed OR there is a better way i can still read the file without having to save it in the cd path shown above?

***P.S*** New to Jupyter notebooks and Python in general

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')
df.head()
```

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      1 # load abc data into data frame
----> 2 df = pd.read_csv('abc.csv')

Comment: Use the full pathname in the read_csv call.  `pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\Studyfolder\abc.csv')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `activate` your anaconda environment, the `jupyter` environment should be tied to that interpreter. In that case, it doesn't really matter *where* you start your notebook from, it will always have access to the libraries installed there. For example:

```
conda activate py3
```

This will now tie `conda` to that environment:

```py
import sys
sys.path
['C:\\Users\\Anaconda3_2\\envs\\py3'...]
```

So you can start `jupyter` wherever, as long as you pass a legitimate path. The full path will work anywhere:

```py
# I'm at C:\Users\Anaconda3

df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Studyfolder\\abc.csv")
```

If you want to use relative paths, it's very dependent on where you call `jupyter notebook` from:

```py
# Still at C:\\Users\\Anaconda3
df = pd.read_csv("..\\Studyfolder\\abc.csv")
```

Where the `..` indicates to go back a directory

Comment: Thanks @C.Nivs - The relative path works great since i had activated the env py3

Answer (score 0):

In general, I would suggest writing your scripts outside the python library in a directory structure that works best for your projects. The simple reason is that your python libraries are already added to `PYTHONPATH` and hence are available anywhere, whereas your project files are only available from your project folders.

In your case, there are two approaches you can take -

- Provide the file location as a relative path to your current directory. So, `df = pd.read_csv('..\..\..\Studyfolder\abc.csv')`
- Add the folder path into your system path by adding these statements before reading your file -

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\\Users\Studyfolder")
```

Comment: Thanks @Abhineed Gupta - I put the fullpath **C:\\Users\\Studyfolder\abc.csv** and it works totally fine..Which means i can run the Anaconda commands on the env that i had enabled in this case - **C:\Users\Anaconda3_2\envs\py3**, but i can still read the file from another directory by putting the relative path / full path as you stated